# HTML drag and drop sortable tables

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html-table

Ever wanted to have an HTML drag and drop sortable table in which you could sort both rows and columns? I know it's something I'd die for. There's a lot of sortable lists going around but finding a sortable table seems to be impossible to find.

I know that you can get pretty close with the tools that script.aculo.us provides but I ran into some cross-browser issues with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [dhtmlxGrid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml) in the past. Among other things it supports drag-and-drop rows/columns, client-side sorting (string, integer, date, custom) and multi-browser support.

Response to comment:
No, not found anything better - just moved on from that project. :-)

Comment: You used it in the past.. Does that mean that you found something better ;) I spent some time digging into it and it seems to be everything i wanted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 24):

I've used jQuery UI's sortable plugin with good results. Markup similar to this:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Details</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="sort">
<tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details1</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details2</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>3</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details3</td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td>4</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and then in the javascript

```
$('.sort').sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    axis:   'y',
    update: function(e, ui) {
        href = '/myReorderFunctionURL/';
        $(this).sortable("refresh");
        sorted = $(this).sortable("serialize", 'id');
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST',
            url:    href,
            data:   sorted,
            success: function(msg) {
                //do something with the sorted data
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This POSTs a serialized version of the items' IDs to the URL given. This function (PHP in my case) then updates the items' orders in the database.

Comment: In case it helps someone else - I had an issue with the example - the `serialize` call was returning null.  It worked when I changed the IDs, as per Lathan's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/966303/1714).  Not sure if it's related to the version of [tag:jquery]

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Sortables](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortables) in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You can use it on list items or pretty much anything, including tables.

jQuery is very cross-browser friendly and I recommend it all the time.

Comment: I couldn't get the jQuery sortable to work in a table. It just drags the whole table around or individual cells. But no row based dragging.

Answer (score 3):

David Heggie's answer was the most useful to me.  It can be slightly more concise:

```
var sort = function(event, ui) {
  var url = "/myReorderFunctionURL/" + $(this).sortable('serialize');
  $.post(url, null,null,"script");  // sortable("refresh") is automatic
}

$(".sort").sortable({
  cursor: 'move',
  axis: 'y',
  stop: sort
});
```

works for me, with the same markup.

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks (Yui, MooTools, jQuery, Prototype/Scriptaculous, etc.) have sortable list functionality. Do a little research into each and pick the one that suits your needs most.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Java, there is a very handy library for GWT called [GWT-DND](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) check out the online demo to see how powerful it is.

Comment: I don't mind Java but someone else might :) 
But seriously, Java feels a bit heavy.

Comment: Using Java because you want a sortable table seems like using a sledgehammer to hammer in a screw.

Answer (score 0):

If you find .serialize() returning null in David Heggie's solution then set the id values for the TRs as 'id_1' instead of simply '1'

Example:

```
<tr id="id_1"><td>1</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details1</td></tr>
<tr id="id_2"><td>2</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details2</td></tr>
<tr id="id_3"><td>3</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details3</td></tr>
<tr id="id_4"><td>4</td><td>Name1</td><td>Details4</td></tr>
```

The above will serialize as "id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3"

You can use '=', '-' or '_' instead of '_'.
And any other word besides "id".

Answer (score 0):

I am using JQuery Sortable to do so but in case, you are using Vue.js like me, here is a solution that creates a custom Vue directive to encapsulate the Sortable functionality, I am aware of Vue draggable but it doesnt sort table columns as per the issue [HERE](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/456) To see this in action, [CHECK THIS](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/VgbRdQ)

**JS Code**

```
Vue.directive("draggable", {
  //adapted from https://codepen.io/kminek/pen/pEdmoo
  inserted: function(el, binding, a) {
    Sortable.create(el, {
      draggable: ".draggable",
      onEnd: function(e) {
        /* vnode.context is the context vue instance: "This is not documented as it's not encouraged to manipulate the vm from directives in Vue 2.0 - instead, directives should be used for low-level DOM manipulation, and higher-level stuff should be solved with components instead. But you can do this if some usecase needs this. */
        // fixme: can this be reworked to use a component?
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4065
        // https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-can-i-access-the-vm-from-a-custom-directive-in-2-0/2548/3
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873 "directive interface change"
        // `binding.expression` should be the name of your array from vm.data
        // set the expression like v-draggable="items"

        var clonedItems = a.context[binding.expression].filter(function(item) {
          return item;
        });
        clonedItems.splice(e.newIndex, 0, clonedItems.splice(e.oldIndex, 1)[0]);
        a.context[binding.expression] = [];
        Vue.nextTick(function() {
          a.context[binding.expression] = clonedItems;
        });

      }
    });
  }
});

const cols = [
  {name: "One", id: "one", canMove: false},
  {name: "Two", id: "two", canMove: true},
  {name: "Three", id: "three", canMove: true},
  {name: "Four", id: "four", canMove: true},
]

const rows = [
  {one: "Hi there", two: "I am so excited to test", three: "this column that actually drags and replaces", four: "another column in its place only if both can move"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "two"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "three"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "four"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "five"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "six"},
  {one: "Hi", two: "I", three: "am", four: "seven"}
]

Vue.component("datatable", {
  template: "#datatable",
  data() {
    return {
      cols: cols,
      rows: rows
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

**CSS**

```
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}

table.table tbody td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Pug Template HTML**

```
#app
  datatable

script(type="text/x-template" id="datatable")
  table.table
    thead(v-draggable="cols")
      template(v-for="c in cols")
        th(:class="{draggable: c.canMove}")
          b-dropdown#ddown1.m-md-2(:text='c.name')
            b-dropdown-item First Action
            b-dropdown-item Second Action
            b-dropdown-item Third Action
            b-dropdown-divider
            b-dropdown-item Something else here...
            b-dropdown-item(disabled='') Disabled action

    tbody
      template(v-for="row in rows")
        tr
          template(v-for="(col, index) in cols")
            td {{row[col.id]}}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)?  That would seem to fit your requirements nicely.

It's rather easy to use - load the sorttable Javascript file, then, for each table you want it to make sortable, apply class="sortable" to the <table> tag.

It will immediately understand how to sort most types of data, but if there's something it doesn't, you can add a custom sort key to tell it how to sort.   The documentation explains it all pretty well.

Comment: Except that there's no dragging nor dropping. I need to be able to sort the table the way i want it row by row, and not by some rule.