# Jquery ui sortable serialize not working

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

Searched all over and I can't find the answer.  I can't get my sortable to serialize.  All I'm getting is null data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#sortable").sortable({
        update : function () {
            serial = $("ul#sortable").sortable("serialize");
            $.ajax({
                url: "sort_images_ajax.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serial,
                error: function(){
                    alert("theres an error with AJAX");
                },
                success: function(feedback){ $("#data").html(feedback); }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="sort_1" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
<li id="sort_2" class="ui-state-default">2</li>
<li id="sort_3" class="ui-state-default">3</li>
</ul>
```

Since I'm using jquery 1.4.2, I found this piece of info here at Stack Overflow:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

With or without that last piece of code, I can't get it to serialize.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This post has been answered in another post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965083/jquery-sortable-list-wont-serialize-why

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem... Apparently, calling .sortable() method from within its event-handler function doesn't work?!

P.S.: Instead of "update" I think you should use "stop" event.

Comment: From the API documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/):

`stop( event, ui ) Type: sortstop
This event is triggered when sorting has stopped.`

`update( event, ui ) Type: sortupdate
This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.`

So from what he seems to be trying to accomplish by taking a look at his code, it seems clear the proper event he needs is the "update" one.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of your code.  Is it possible that your IDs are not unique?