# How can I stagger a Sortable list in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to build a hierarchy of sorts with a sortable list -- nothing fancy, just nudge each element of to the right a bit, so it clearly shows the hierarchy.

Has anyone seen a technique for this?  I thought about it for a minute and thought that if I initially draw the list, I could just bump the left margin a bit for each

.

But then I realized that I wouldn't know how to handle renumbering on sort... I guess I could call a function on STOP and change the margin left to each element... (did I just answer my own question?)

Regardless, does anyone know of an existing answer to this?  I would think someone would have already done this.

Comment: Can you provide sample input/output for this? It's not clear exactly what you're asking for...

Comment: So I make a LIST in HTML  (ul, li) --- I want that list so that every element is staggered to the right (so it looks like steps or a hierarchy).
BUT this list is also set to be SORTABLE via JQuery - so when I SORT the list (say I drag the 5th list item up to the 2nd place), I want the stagger to fix itself.

Comment: This link has a staggered list similar to what you have asked for. http://www.drakedata.com/serializetree/sampleTree.html Link was originally posted in the below thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965083/jquery-sortable-list-wont-serialize-why/1922045#1922045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

**Nestable** - http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/

**nestedSortable** - http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Either one should do exactly what you need.

[image: Nestable]