# jquery sortable serialize returns empty string

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

HTML:

```
<ul id="categories_list" class="ui-sortable">
<li class="cat_row" style=""> item1 </li>
<li class="cat_row" style=""> item2 </li>
<li class="cat_row"> item3 </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#categories_list").sortable({
placeholder: 'sortable_placeholder',
update : function () {
    var order = $("#categories_list").sortable('serialize');
    console.log(order);
} 
});
```

order returns "empty string" why is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The id attributes on your li's need to look like this:

```
<ul id="categories_list" class="ui-sortable">
<li class="catRow_1" style=""> item1 </li>
<li class="catRow_2" style=""> item2 </li>
<li class="catRow_3"> item3 </li>
</ul>
```

You need to have the order number seperated by an underscore as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965083/jquery-sortable-list-wont-serialize-why).

Comment: using <li id="catRow_1"> instead of <li class="catRow_1"> aso  works, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> Serializes the sortable's **item id's** into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.

You'll need to specify id's for the LI-Tags!

See
http://jsfiddle.net/m47mq/